# Trying to print with spaces instead of line changes

Tags: python, spaces

I'm just discovering Python, and I can't find a way to avoid a line change between each word I want to print.
I know it must be a often people often ask, and that's why I looked for the answer, but couldn't find anything which works.
I've read it once was possible to put a comma at the end of my print command, but it has stopped to work this way since a new version of Pyzo was released.
I also read about typing print(bla, sep=" ") but it doesn't work, so basically I don't know what to do. 
Here's what I typed :

```
from random import *
def vocabulaire(x):
i=1
while i<=x/2:
    print(choice(français, sep=""))
    i=i+1
while x>=i>x/2:
    print(choice(anglais,sep=""))
    i=i+1
```

Basically, if I try and execute this programm, Pyzo prints :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    from random import *
  File "C:\Users\Sébastien\Desktop\Pyzo_TD1.py", line 86, in vocabulaire
    # The full license can be found in 'license.txt'.
TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sep' "
```

The program does work if I just delete the " sep="" ", but not the way I'd like it to.

Do you know what I should do ?
(I may have done some grammar mistakes in this post, sorry about that, I'm not fluent in english)

Ps : "français" and "anglais" are two lists

Answer (score 2):

`sep` is a parameter to `print`, not to `choice`. So, code should have been like this

```
print(choice(français), sep=" ")
...
print(choice(anglais), sep=" ")
```

If you actually wanted to print them in a single line, you should use `end` parameter, not the `sep` parameter, like this

```
print(choice(français), end=" ")
...
print(choice(anglais), end=" ")
```

Comment: Thanks for having answered so fast :) anyway, it still doesn't work, even after this change

Comment: Well no, the program works the same way it would without sep=" "

Comment: @user3024631 It doesn't say on their site, but curious as to what: `import sys; print(sys.version)` shows you...

Comment: @user3024631 Does your program really have space between the quotes?

Comment: I suspect it isn't that `sep=''` is required, the trailing comma is mentioned, so I'm guessing it's `end=''` (or whatever) that 's required

Comment: 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: I hadn't forgotten the spaces, and the program is just supposed to print X english/french words, it was just a way for me to study two subjects at the same time. But anyway, problem solved :) Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

If you don not want to change line , just add ',' i.e:

```
print "aaa",
print "bbb"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
import random

def vocabulaire(x, list_one, list_two):
    i = 1
    while i <= x/2:
        print random.choice(list_one),
        i += 1
    while x >= i > x/2:
        print random.choice(list_two),
        i += 1
```

If you are not sure how to use a function, such as *random.choice*, you can use *ipython* to get some help. For example, in the shell, type

```
$ ipython
```

then, in *ipython*, type the following statements:

```
import random
help(random.choice)
```

May they will help :)